# Why doesn't JavaScript let you call methods on numbers directly?

Tags: javascript

In Ruby, you can do this:

```
3.times { print "Ho! " } # => Ho! Ho! Ho!
```

I tried to do it in JavaScript:

```
Number.prototype.times = function(fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this; i++) {
        fn();
    }
}
```

This works:

```
(3).times(function() { console.log("hi"); });
```

This doesn't

```
3.times(function() { console.log("hi"); });
```

Chrome gives me a syntax error: "Unexpected token ILLEGAL". Why?

Comment: ... Because JavaScript isn't Ruby? That's like asking "Why doesn't cobol work like Ruby?".

Comment: @Incognito um, no? I'm asking why it's a syntax error, not why it doesn't work like ruby...

Comment: Can you explain the rational behind talking about ruby in the first place and maintain consistency with that statement?

Comment: @Incognito I wanted to re-create that method, so I just mentioned what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @Incognito obviously Ruby is a bad thing to bring up in a JS question so I won't bother with that again...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `.` after the digits represents the decimal point of the number, you'll have to use another one to access a property or method.

```
3..times(function() { console.log("hi"); });
```

This is only necessary for decimal literals. For octal and hexadecimal literals you'd use only one `.`.

```
03.times(function() { console.log("hi"); });//octal
0x3.times(function() { console.log("hi"); });//hexadecimal
```

Also exponential

```
3e0.times(function() { console.log("hi"); });
```

You can also use a space since a space in a number is invalid and then there is no ambiguity.

```
3 .times(function() { console.log("hi"); });
```

Although as stated by `wxactly` in the comments a minifier would remove the space causing the above syntax error.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Interesting that it can also represent a decimal point in Ruby but it still works.

Comment: I go against doing 2 dots since it is very likely to create confusion for the reader. Parantheses are more self descriptive.

Comment: @AlexCoplan I'm guessing because Ruby has integer and float types, but JavaScript just has Number

Comment: The last example utilizing a space is interesting to know, but unsafe to rely on... When you run that code through a minifier, BAM your syntax error shows up again.