# float.toString() is working but integer.toString() is not working why?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 2;

a.toString(); // "2"  Works 

2.20.toString(); // "2.2" Works

2..toString(); // "2" Also works  as '2.' is a valid float number 
a.toString(); // "2" Works
```

But

```
2.toString(); // Throw error
```

I am curious to know why javascript is working as it is working ?

Comment: Similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272581/why-doesnt-javascript-let-you-call-methods-on-numbers-directly

Comment: OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380077/why-cant-i-access-a-property-of-an-integer-with-a-single-dot