# Why are Strings JavaScript Primitives?

Tags: javascript

I'm not a JavaScript newbie, but I was reading MDN page on primitive data types and it caught my attention the following line:

> A primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not an object and **has no methods**. In JavaScript, there are 6 primitive data types: string, number, boolean, null, undefined, symbol (new in ECMAScript 2015).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

If primitives have no methods, then why is it possible to do this in JavaScript:

`'HELLO WORLD'.toLowerCase() // result: hello world`

Why isn't that invalid? Shouldn't that throw an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" just as the following statement does:

`2.toString()`

Comment: `length` is a property not a method

Comment: @klugjo irrelevant in this context, but edited for clarity.

Comment: might want to read this: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/

Comment: true.toString() does not give an error

Comment: seems misleading since most have prototype methods

Comment: The reason `2.toString()` fails is compilers always look at dot after number as decimal and expect number to follow. Can do `(2).toString()`

Comment: `2.toString()` gives an error because the `.` is considered a decimal point.  `2..toString()` maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272581/why-doesnt-javascript-let-you-call-methods-on-numbers-directly

Comment: I believe you have discovered a mistake in MDN, well done! The ECMA specification's [definition of "primitive"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primitive-value) says nothing about whether one should or should not have methods.